# Twig "trans with" not working

Tags: php, twig, translation

I'm using the twig `trans` tag in my templates, and I want to pass variables in it like so:

```
{% trans with {
   '%link_start%': '<a href="http://www.google.nl/">',
   '%link_end%': '</a>'
} %}
    This %link_start%disclaimer%link_end% applies to all of our messages.
{% endtrans %}
```

But this gives me the following exception which points to the twig template at the `{% trans with` line:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" ("end of statement block" expected).' in [twig-template:line]

Even when I copy & paste the examples from the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#twig-templates) I get the same exception. So I'm at a loss, what am I doing wrong here?

FYI: I'm using Twig 1.33 with the i18n extension enabled (and I'm not using the Symfony framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twig doesn't support `trans with` out of the box. It is part of the Symfony translation extension. That explains why even the official Symfony documentation doesn't work - you are not using Symfony.

See this issue: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions/issues/74. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions/pull/138) to support `trans with`, but it hasn't been merged.

You might want to use the [Symfony Translation Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation.html) in your application. You  can use Symfony Components in your application, even without using the full Symfony (Framework) stack.

I haven't tried it, but you can try to use [jhogervorst/Twi18n](https://github.com/jhogervorst/Twi18n) instead.

Comment: Ah well, that explains the missing doc-pages on the official twig site. But thanks for your answer! I think I'll use the SF Translation Component since it is more frequently updated than jhogeverst's Twi18n.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use the [`filter` tag](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/filter.html) with [`replace`](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/replace.html).

```
{% filter replace({'%foo%': 'blue', '%bar%': 'red'}) %}
  {% trans %}
    I like %foo% and %bar% messages.
  {% endtrans %}
{% endfilter %}
```